# AfterGlowPlayer after setting dynamically data-youtube-id video won't play

Tags: javascript, jquery

I im using this video player:

http://docs.afterglowplayer.com/docs/playing-a-youtube-video

and after i dynamically add data-youtube-id i im unable to play video..do i need call with another way?

my script of reading glowplayer2 class and appending it to glowplayer3 class that can center glowplayer on the screen (glowplayer2 class is hidden div that contains php generated url)

```
$(".afterglowplayer2").click(function () {
     switch(true) {
       case /imdb/.test($("#myvideo video", this).attr("src")):
          alert("IMDB!");
          $(".afterglowplayer3 #myvideo video").attr("src", $("#myvideo video", this).attr("src"))
          break;
       default:
          alert("YOUTUBE");
          $(".afterglowplayer3 #myvideo video").attr("data-youtube-id", $("#myvideo video", this).attr("src")).removeAttr("src");
          break;
     }
     $.afterglowplayer.toggle(".afterglowplayer3");
     return false;
  });
```

After that code i get this:

```
<video class="vjs-tech" id="myvideo_html5_api" data-ratio="0.5625" style="padding-top: 56.25%;" preload="auto" data-youtube-id="XpICoc65uh0"></video>
```

So you see that correct data-youtube-id is set using above jQuery function but video is not playing...why? If i set it manually in html code it plays normally...but i need to change and remove src if is youtube video and if is not add src attribute to video tag...

Answer (score 0):

You should put their respective class (`afterglow`) and size

```
<video class="afterglow vjs-tech" width="960" height="540"...
```

edit *[Your code](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) -> [is misspelled](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp).*

```
$(".afterglowplayer2").click(function () {
   if(/imdb/.test($("#uniqueid", this).attr("src")){
      alert("IMDB!");
      $("#uniqueid").attr("src", $("#uniqueid", this).attr("src"))
   } else {
      alert("YOUTUBE");
      $("#uniqueid").attr("data-youtube-id", $("#uniqueid", this).attr("src")).removeAttr("src");
   }
   $.afterglowplayer.toggle(".afterglowplayer3");
   return false;
});
```

Comment: I added this class but it won't play...i don't know why is not play...console is empty (no error), data-youtube-id="XpICoc65uh0" and class afterglow vjs-tech added...if i add url it plays others video fine...but if i add data-youtube-id it wont play..maybe i need like src have load();

Comment: @John see the answer :)

Comment: Thanks AvrilAlejandro but i don't see any difference in code...it is like i posted above except you added #uniqueid...could you be please more specific where i im doing it wrong?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp